# Discord bot stickers

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is there a way that I can get my discord bot to send stickers after somebody says a certain thing, I got normal messages and emojis to work while it replies but there is not much learning material to find out how to get stickers to work with discord.py.

This is my code :

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.nerd ', description = 'nerd eyes')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    guild_count = 0

    for guild in bot.guilds:

        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")

        guild_count = guild_count + 1

    print('Nerdeyes has awoken in ' + str(guild_count) + " servers")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('nerd'):
        msg = 'eyes'
        await message.channel.send(msg)

    if message.content.startswith('guy'):
        msg = '<:guysusthink:873066296558882847>'
        await message.channel.send(msg)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 2):

Stickers are a new Discord feature and haven't been added yet in `Discord.py`. You're gonna have to wait a bit until they release the new version.

Comment: It would really help if maybe you could link a good and updated tutorial on how to make the bot send images

Comment: @Ancient see the FAQ in the API docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=images#how-do-i-upload-an-image